# Dropping video frames

Tags: c++, algorithm, frames

my question is pretty simple, I think. And it's more about math than coding. 
I receive 15 frames per second from web-cam. But I have to drop some of these. For example, if client is requesting 8 fps - I do drop each second frame and it's ok. But how should I drop if 12 fps or 6 fps are requested?

I think there's some common algo for values distribution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By dropping every 2nd frame for 8 fps, if you are having 15 fps, you are introducing an error.

This is a very simple algorithm, that would work in all cases :

```
#include <iostream>

double t = 0.0;

const double fps1 = 15.0;
const double fps2 = 12.0;

const double t1 = 1.0 / fps1;
const double t2 = 1.0 / fps2;

// true - drop the frame
// false - do NOT drop the frame
bool NextTick()
{
  t += t1;
  if ( t > t2 )
  {
    t -= t2;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  for ( unsigned int i =0;i<20;++i)
  {
      if ( NextTick() )
      {
          std::cout<<"dropping the frame"<<std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout<<"display the frame"<<std::endl;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code. But I had fps2 = 15 too. And for loop up to 15*10 (10 second of video, 15fps). By the end of algo I had 1 frame dropped :) Not good...

Comment: The algorithm above is the standard way of limiting FPS. Most likely some rounding kick in for the 1st check.

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry - that really looks like some rounding kick. If it will be faster than mine - I will use it! //Gone to check

Comment: I'm sure this thing does not take into consideration that the frame may come at variable intervals. Delays can be larger in some portions and smaller in another. This will reject a frame wrongly if t<t2 && t+t1<t2 and frame has appeared after a very long delay.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've seen this done (e.g. in gstreamer) is to have two asynchronous loops, one receiving the frames from the camera and one sending the frames to the client.  The latter loop only has the most recently captured frame from the camera available to it and so frames that aren't "picked up" by the client are automatically dropped as they're overwritten by the next incoming frame.

You need to do a little bit of synchronising to make sure you don't read half captured frames but other than that it's a straight forward solution and allows both sides of the interchange to operate at different speeds in either direction.

Comment: I dont understand why everybody votes this answer up? Saying loop - u mean thread? It's not good to add a thread for such an easy task I think. It can be handled in one and only thread.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you need is to drill a bit deeper into FPS concept.

A FPS of X means a frame is presented to display every 1/X sec and it remains visible on the display for 1/X sec. Typically the frames are updated on the display at every vertical sync of the display device.

Now with this information, frame rate conversion can be visualized as decoder decoding to temporary display at input FPS and a sampler displaying frames on final display at output FPS. The sampler samples frame from the temporary display on which decoder is updating frames. This logic should ensure synchronization between decoder and sampler such that sampler does not end up sampling partially updated frames.

This logic work for both decreasing or increasing FPS.

This can be implemented as single buffer with synchronized access. Now let decoder write to this buffer at input FPS and sampler pick frame from this buffer and display at output fps.

This will ensure screen updates are uniform and latest available frame is displayed at vertical sync.

Comment: The question was not about the screen

Answer (score 1):

Have a ring buffer large enough to hold 1 full second of video.

Into this buffer write each video frame. Update a variable pointing to that was written to.

In a seperate thread use a timer to delay a period of 1000 / desired_fps (84ms for 12fps) and pick the last frame written to and send that.

Comment: I like this solution. But I dont like adding one more thread.

Comment: Why not? Jesse and I have given very similar answers which both require a thread. Sometimes, even though a situation is simple, the simplist way is to use a thread. I have threads in applications where the setup and teardown logic for the thread outweighs the internal logic that the thread performs.  Anyway you could use the same thread as the capturing but you run the risk of skipping the frame you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

What can you say about such solution:

I have 15 static const byte arrays with 0s and 1s. 1 - show frame, 0 - no. When I receive frame I increment counter cnt = [0..15] and look where does it point - zero or one. That's how I decide whether to show or drop frame.

I think this solution is easier and faster then implementing new thread.

Comment: That solution sort of works, though I think there still might be the risk of dropping frames you don't want to drop because if you only have one thread it is going to be busy either reading from the camera or writing to the output most of the time and if it's doing the wrong one at the wrong time, you might end up missing an incoming frame (depending on how the buffering works).  The other problem you have with this solution is what happens when your webcam breaks and you buy a new one that starts sending 24fps (for example) or your client wants to show 10fps (for example)?

Comment: By doing that you introduce big rounding error. But if it suits your need, go ahead

Comment: Well, now I see that your solution is more precise. But mine is 3-4 times faster. And for now - I'll use mine. But anyway, thanks a lot!